# AVFoundation - playing wav files (outside application bundle) Swift 2.1

Tags: swift, macos, swift2, command-line-interface, avaudioplayer

I'm just experimenting a bit with Swift (for the first time). Error checking and proper application structure aside, I thought this should play audio:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
let file = "/Users/mtwomey/Desktop/test1/test1/a2002011001-e02.wav"

let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: file)
print(url)
audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: file), fileTypeHint: "wav")
audioPlayer.play()
print("Done.")
```

It does not however. When I run this application it simply proceeds to print "Done." and exit. If the filename / filepath is incorrect, I get an exception (so it appears to actually be accessing the file).

I'm trying to prove a concept for a console application which will need to access wave files which are outside the application bundle. Any tips on what I'm missing?

Comment: Playgrounds are sandboxed. Have you tried it with an actual OSX project?

Comment: @LeoDabus - Yes, I'm running it right in Xcode (7.1.1) with the above being the entire contents of the single source file (main.swift).

Comment: I mean a full project with a window/view, not playground

Comment: @LeoDabus - This will be for a command line utility, there won't be any windows / views. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding? (quite possible)

Comment: Just to further clarify - this is a project, not a playground.

Comment: I am facing the same problem!! No errors, but the iPad isn't playing the .wav file in my case.

Comment: Just declare the player as class variable! @MPT Take a look at my answer below. It worked for me.

Comment: Doesn’t the app finish before the player plays? Try adding a delay after play so the app doesn’t exit.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out  that the main issue of not being able to play audio when executing your swift file was that: *Command Line Tool exits before the AVAudioPlayer gets ready to play* (Before asynchronous operations complete).

Here is my solution (using **DispatchGroup**) which could play my mp3 file by executing my **Swift file** (written in Swift 5.x) from a **Command Line Tool** (no Playground).

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

var testAudio = AVAudioPlayer()

let path = FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath + "/example.mp3"

let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()


DispatchQueue.main.async {
    do {
        testAudio = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    } catch let err {
        print("Failed play audio: \(err)")
    }
    
    group.leave()
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("play audio")
    testAudio.play()
}

dispatchMain()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: AVAudioPlayerDelegate{
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!  // Declaring this outside your function, as class variable is important! otherwise your player won't be able to play the sound.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.playSound("/Users/mtwomey/Desktop/test1/test1/a2002011001-e02.wav")
}

func playSound(soundPath: String)
{
    let sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundPath)
    do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound, fileTypeHint: "wav")
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.delegate = self
        audioPlayer.play()
    }catch {
        print("Error getting the audio file")
    }
}
```

or (if you already have placed the file in your project) (Follow this [blog post](http://budiirawan.com/ios-play-sound-swift/) to find out how to place the file in your project)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: AVAudioPlayerDelegate{
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!  // Declaring this outside your function, as class variable is important! otherwise your player won't be able to play the sound.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.playSound("sound-name")
}

func playSound(soundName: String)
{
    let sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(soundName, ofType: "wav")!)
    do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound, fileTypeHint: "wav")
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.delegate = self
        audioPlayer.play()
    }catch {
        print("Error getting the audio file")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a Mac console / command line app though (not mobile) - I'm trying to tweak the hints I'm getting from your answer to that end.

Comment: I don't know, maybe this is just the wrong use case. Maybe I should just go back to c++ for console apps. Since this deals with audio, I thought I might save time with Swift.